# ViewPager cause crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a viewpager. The viewpager has five fragments. And these fragments have child fragments. When I start my app, it crashes. If I comment out resetMenu() function it works. What is the problem?

**HomeActivity.java**

```
 @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        listeners[beforePagerPosition].onViewPaused();
        tabLayout.getTabAt(beforePagerPosition).getIcon().setAlpha(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.tab_unselected_alpha));

        beforePagerPosition = position;
        tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getIcon().setAlpha(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.tab_selected_alpha));
        listeners[position].onViewResumed();
        resetMenu();
        hideKeyboard();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    private void resetMenu() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager() != null) {
            ParentFragment parentFragment = (ParentFragment) listeners[viewPager.getCurrentItem()];
            FragmentManager fm = parentFragment.getChildFragmentManager();
            if (fm != null && fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backStackEntry = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
                String str = backStackEntry.getName();
                BaseMenuFragment fragment = (BaseMenuFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(str);
                fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you post crash logs  ?

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found answer. I added control for `ParentFragment isAdded()`.

```
ParentFragment parentFragment = (ParentFragment) listeners[viewPager.getCurrentItem()];
    if(parentFragment.isAdded()){
       ....

    }
```